# Error: Uncaught [Error: Passed an incorrect argument to a color function, please pass a string representation of a color

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, storybook

I'm having an issue with a button react component using `opacify` function from [Polished Library](https://polished.js.org/docs/)

I'm using styled-components for styling and a theme using `ThemeProvider` to pass the theme to be used. When I test the code it's returning this error, I'm using also storybook, any help is appreciated :)

```
export const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps>  = styled(ButtonUI)` 
&.ui.button{

 &.inverted {
  background: ${props => opacify(-0.20, props.theme.greySteel)}!important;
 }
}
```

the error in my yarn test:

```
Passed an incorrect argument to a color function, please pass a string representation of a color.

&.inverted {
    > 52 |        background: ${props => opacify(-0.20, props.theme.greySteel)}!important;
         |                               ^
```

Props are being passed like:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={dark}>
```

In storyboard:

```
const withGlobalStyles = (storyFn : any) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ThemeProvider theme={dark}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      {storyFn()}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

My theme object looks like this:

```
 export const dark: Palette = {
    greySteel: '#2E313F',

    }
```

My App.js

```
<ThemeProvider theme={dark}>

</ThemeProvider>
```

My stories.tsx file

```
export const storyBuilder = (
      scenarios: Scenarios,
      storyPath: string,
      pageTemplate?: React.FC<any>,
    ) => {
      const Template: React.FC = pageTemplate || noTemplate;
      const stories = storiesOf(storyPath, module);
      stories.addDecorator(withKnobs as any);
      stories.addDecorator(withGlobalStyles as any)

      Object.keys(scenarios).forEach(key => {
        stories.add(key, () => (
          <ThemeProvider theme={dark}>
            <Provider store={store}>
              <Router>
                <Template>
                  <div>
                    {scenarios[key](knobs)}
                  </div>
                </Template>
              </Router>
            </Provider>
          </ThemeProvider>
        ))
      })
    };
```

I found answers over the internet but none of them has helped me, thanks in advance

Comment: Please tell us the value of `props.theme.greySteel` we can't guess it

Comment: the change works fine while I'm running the app but it fails while testing the component. The test only mounts the component. I updated the object

Comment: Please provide a producible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), how are you using `withGlobalStyles`, where you define it?

Comment: Updated the code again

Comment: You storyBuilder doesn't make sense, when applying `withGlobalStyles` you got two ThemeProviders for every story

Comment: This was a test I removed and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

`opacify` accepts color as string:

```
opacify(-0.20, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)')
```

According to the error, `greySteel` is NOT a `color` string.

Therefore make sure it's a string, you can use helpers like `rgbToColorString`, and make sure it is defined:

```
opacify(-0.20, rgbToColorString({ red: 255, green: 205, blue: 100 }))
```

```
background: ${props => opacify(-0.20, props.theme.greySteel || rgbToColorString({ red: 255, green: 205, blue: 100 }) )}!important;
```

Comment: My application was passing in undefined to this function, so it failed.